# How to convert datetime to a timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any method to calculate a list of dateTime.datetime(2018,11,24,22,44,36) values to a timestamp with Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python)